# How to access a "website" being served by a PC connected to another PC

Tags: xampp

If I use XAMPP to set up a website on a pc, how can i connect to it and surf it from another PC connected via LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you connect to it from internet - use xampp´s computer ip adress :)